# ".gitlab-ci.yml": how to define multiple projects in "trigger"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project "my_project_0" that must trigger pipelines of all my other projects ("my_project_1", "my_project_2", etc.).

What I want:

```yaml
  stage: multi_project_test
  trigger:
    project: "my_project_1"
    strategy: depend
  trigger:
    project: "my_project_2"
    strategy: depend
  trigger:
    project: "my_project_3"
    strategy: depend
```

...but I have the error `Key 'trigger' is duplicated`.

The official page about [Multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html) is useless because it has no examples for multi-projects pipelines (only for a parent-child trigger).

What is the correct syntax to trigger pipelines of multiple projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to create a bridge job for each downstream pipeline you want to trigger.

For example:

```yaml
downstream 1/3:
  stage: multi_project_test
  trigger:
    project: project-1
    strategy: depend

downstream 2/3:
  stage: multi_project_test
  trigger:
    project: project-2
    strategy: depend

downstream 3/3:
  stage: multi_project_test
  trigger:
    project: project-3
    strategy: depend
```

I haven't tested this, but you *should* be able to use `parallel:matrix` to define the same thing as above in a concise manner:

```yaml
downstream_pipelines:
  stage: multi_project_test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT: ["project-1", "project-2", "project-3"]
  trigger:
    project: $DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT
    strategy: depend
```

Comment: When I use `parallel: matrix:`, I have an error `downstream project could not be found`. Well, then I will use the first example...

Comment: `parallel: matrix` works fine! great tip

Comment: @Kappacake parallel:matrix works for me too but can we add conditions to it?

Comment: Sample code
`Job_1:
  stage: development
  variables:
    application: "app3"
    name: $GITLAB_USER_NAME
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - PROJECT: xyz/integration/project1
        CONDITION: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" || CI_COMMIT_TAG ) && $APP_NAME="app1"
      - PROJECT: xyz/ui/project2
        CONDITION: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" || CI_COMMIT_TAG) && $APP_NAME="app2"
  trigger:
    project: $PROJECT
    branch: main
    strategy: depend`
I added these conditions suggested by chatGPT but looks like the conditions are not being evaluated at all. Is this valid code?

Comment: @Parineetha consider asking a separate question. I notice at least one error: `=` instead of `==` in your condition checking `$APP_NAME`

Comment: @sytech: Do you know if there is an upper limit for the number of the downstream projects?

Comment: @TreefishZhang yes, sort of. There are both [rate limits for pipeline creation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/instance_limits.html#pipeline-creation-rate-limit) as well as [CICD limits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/instance_limits.html#cicd-limits) that may apply if you have **a lot** of triggers or lots of jobs in each pipeline. On gitlab.com, rate limits are in effect to prevent abuse of pipelines -- the CICD limits are defined depending on the subscription plan. On self-hosted gitlab, the GitLab administrator controls the rate limits and CICD limits.